# Papaparse Error: [Trailing quote on quoted field is malformed]

Tags: csv, papaparse, csvreader, react-papaparse

Getting an error "Trailing quote on quoted field is malformed"
parsing csv with the data

```
Price,section,title.fr,Description.fr
6,5042773806456766485,"some text ""some text""",25cl
```

I attempted to parse the given CSV data using a Papaparse parsing library. However, I encountered an error message that said 'Trailing quote on quoted field is malformed.' I was expecting the parsing process to complete successfully without any errors, allowing me to work with the CSV data in my application. Unfortunately, I need assistance in resolving this error and correctly parsing the data.

Comment: I just tried your data in the Papa Parse Demo https://www.papaparse.com/demo and it seems to work just fine.  Is it possible that there is a space after the comma and before your quoted text? I found this online as a possible issue.  https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/537#issuecomment-407870637

Comment: The only way I seem to be able to get that error is if I put something besides a double quote at the end before the `,25cl`.

Comment: Show your code in a [mcve] that we can copy and run with *no changes* to reproduce the error